# java setText in loop

Tags: java, loops, sleep

Hi im trying to setText to JTextArea in loop but I want to do it, thtat in each loop every line will be seen in frame.

I have tryied with `Thread.sleep(500)`, becouse I thought loop is too fast to set each line, but its didnt help.

Is it possible ?? to do it ? I want to do it to show to user progress with downloading files from database.

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could see what you have so far.

Comment: @Hunter what U want to see the loop ? or how I create xml file using data from query

Comment: @skowron-line You should try what Bala is suggesting. setText() is probably overwriting what you previously wrote.

Comment: I had `setText(area.getText() + "...")` so it wasnt overwriting anything

Comment: ok, well post your loop and we'll look at what you are doing.

Comment: @hunter there is too much code so simple `for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
 area.setText(area.getText() + "\n ...");
 try{
  Thread.sleep(500);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 
 }
} `

Comment: How is the loop called? is it in a swing event handler?

Comment: What is that printing to the JTextArea? anything?

Comment: @fgb its a simple loop showing results from query, @hunter this is a name of locations geting from database something like `abc shop ... [OK]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the nature of event-based singlethreaded guis makes it so that the changes are only visible once the event is fully handled (returned from the event handler)

blocking the event dispatch thread won't help (and even *makes the entire app unresponsive*)

you should use a timer to simulate the adding one at the time with a delay in between

```
final String[] lines;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    Timer t = new Timer(500*i,new ActionListener(){
        int ind=i;
        void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            area.setText(area.getText() + "\n ..."); 
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

this creates 10 timers each adding a line after some time (increments of 500)
there's a better way to do this that reuses the timer and stops it after everything is done but it's a bit more verbose

Comment: @skowon-line Careful here: this is a `javax.swing.Timer` not a `java.util.Timer`.

Answer (score 2):

I think `JTextArea.append(text)` might be more useful.

Comment: i think it is just append(text).